# Get micronaut to use my instance of `JacksonConfiguration`

Tags: java, micronaut

I'm trying to get micronaut (1.2.6) to use my code to instantiate a `JacksonConfiguration` instead of the default mechanism.

I have this:

```java
@Factory
public class MyFactory {

    @Singleton
    public JacksonConfiguration jacksonConfiguration() {
        JacksonConfiguration cfg = new JacksonConfiguration();
        System.out.println("jacksonConfiguration() - hashcode is " + System.identityHashCode(cfg));
        return cfg;
    }

    @Factory
    public static class MyObjectMapperFactory extends ObjectMapperFactory {
        @Override
        @Singleton @Replaces(ObjectMapper.class)
        public ObjectMapper objectMapper(@Nullable JacksonConfiguration jacksonConfiguration, @Nullable JsonFactory jsonFactory) {
            System.out.println("objectMapper()         - hashcode is " + System.identityHashCode(jacksonConfiguration));
            return super.objectMapper(jacksonConfiguration, jsonFactory);
        }
    }

}
```

and, while the `ObjectMapper` factory receives and instance of `JacksonConfiguration`, my other method is never called.

I tried adding `@Replaces(JacksonConfiguration.class)` to my `jacksonConfiguration()` method, but that causes the `ObjectMapper` factory method to be called with `null` instead of an instance of `JacksonConfiguration` (no idea why).

What should I do to replace the default `JacksonConfiguraion`?

*PS:
I know I can just ignore it and instantiate my `ObjectMappers` any way I want (that's what I'll do until I understand this issue).
The point here is more understanding how micronaut works than finding a solution/workaround to a specific practical problem.*

Comment: The bug is that your bean isn't being added as one of the possible candidates. So replacing the other bean is causing the other bean to be disabled, thus there are no candidates. Once you use a version where the bug is resolved your bean will be injected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code I would expect a NonUniqueBean exception to be thrown because there would be multiple JacksonConfiguration beans. You should configure yours to `@Replaces(JacksonConfiguration.class)`.

Note there was a bug related to replacing configuration properties beans that was resolved in 1.3.0.M1 and the latest 1.2.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT so you will need to use one of those versions

Comment: With `@Replace` it's even worse (see opening post for details). Thanks for the head's up on the bug – I wasn't able to find the report but I'll assume its it and come back after 1.2.8 is out.

Comment: There was no report - your question led me to it and I fixed it

Comment: Oh! That's why you seem to be following the micronaut tag here! Nice to know you devs are so supportive!