# How to get Micronaut not to ignore errors/typos in the configuration file?

Tags: micronaut

Micronaut seems to silently ignore errors/typos in the configuration file, which is generally frustrating and particularly annoying when – like with CORS – the default it reverts to is less secure than one could desire.

Is there a way to tell Micronaut (1.3.0.M1) to explode in the most spectacular manner at the slightest hint of misconfiguration?

Alternatively, how can I configure everything via Java code and drop the `.yml` file?

*Edit:*

For the specific issue with CORS, I ended up extending `io.micronaut.http.server.cors.CorsFilter` and passing my own `CorsConfiguration` to the `super()` constructor.

The problem with Micronaut not helping to detect bad configuration, however, is general and has frustrated me more than once during this project.

Comment: How could Micronaut assume the configuration is bad? Just because it doesn't read it doesn't mean its not used somewhere else. If have any ideas for improvements please file an issue

Comment: I mean, if for example I write "configuations" (missing "r") and there is no "setConfiguations()" (again, missing "r") I would love it to explode rather than merrily carrying on :-)

Comment: How would Micronaut know you aren't using that configuration key?

Comment: "Is there a way to tell Micronaut (1.3.0.M1) to explode in the most spectacular manner at the slightest hint of misconfiguration?" - No.

Comment: The example that you asked for in the comment where "configuations" should cause Micronaut to "explode", would be a bad idea.  It would break much of the framework.

Comment: Using "configuation" as a config key is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the existing configuration beans with your own. You shouldn't have to extend the filter itself. Alternatively you can create `BeanCreatedEventListeners` to be able to set the configuration on the existing beans.

```
@Replaces(HttpServerConfiguration.CorsConfiguration.class)
@Singleton
class MyConfiguration extends HttpServerConfiguration.CorsConfiguration
```

or

```
@Singleton
class CorsConfigurationListener implements BeanCreatedEventListener<HttpServerConfiguration.CorsConfiguration>
```

Comment: I tried the first one with no success (may be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160012/get-micronaut-to-use-my-instance-of-jacksonconfiguration again, may be that I have to `@Replace` the whole `HttpServerConfiguration`, or... I might be just dumb). I'll try the `BeanCreatedEventListener` way, thanks! (I need to familiarize more with micronaut internals).